# Animating TikZ without beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[white] (1,1) circle (2pt);
    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{(10-\n)*90/10}
      \draw<\n>[thick,dashed,->] (1,0) node[below]{%
        Rotating by $90^\circ$%
      } arc (0:\ang:1);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which yields a nice(?) animation of a growing arrow. Now, I want to generate one PDF file where each page contains one cropped slide - as if I was using `standalone`. Cropped means for me that it will contain only the result of the `tikz` environment, and nothing else (not even border or something like that).

I tried to use `standalone` with the `multi=true` but then it doesn't crop the page, and I don't know how to generate a loop there...

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E. g., by means of the `preview` package.

Instead of placing an invisible dot at the top edge you could use something like

```
%\fill[white] (1,1) circle (2pt);
\useasboundingbox (-0.25,-0.45) rectangle (2.2,1.05);
```

to fine-tune the picture bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[white] (1,1) circle (2pt);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{(10-\n)*90/10}
    \draw[thick,dashed,->] (1,0) node[below]{%
      Rotating by $90^\circ$%
    } arc (0:\ang:1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `standalone` class does understand the option `tikz`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[white] (1,1) circle (2pt);
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{(10-\n)*90/10}
      \draw [thick,dashed,->] (1,0) node[below]{%
        Rotating by $90^\circ$%
      } arc (0:\ang:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

### Output[image]